# Find lines in (multiple) files that contain the given line in an input file

Tags: text-processing, files, awk, grep

If I have a number of files like the following:

`file1`:

```
123
456
789
012
```

`file2`:

```
line1  922
line2  392
line3  456
line5  291
line6  201
...
```

`file3`:

```
line1  111
line2  123
line3  19
line5  542
line6  456
...
```

What's the best way to get all of the lines in `file1` which are contained in a line of *both* `file2` and `file3`?

In this example, it would be just:

```
456
```

Comment: are lines just these numbers or is there anything more in them?

Comment: @Fiximan it's in this format - but longer numbers and different text instead of line1, etx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -of file1 file2|xargs -I {} grep -o "{}" file3
```

This starts by taking the input of file1 and feeding it in line by line into file2, returning the exact matched text if any. Then the results if any are fed into file3 line by line again returning only matched text.

Comment: Follow up - is there a way that this would still work if, for example, by excluding substrings in the first part of a line of file2 that matches the line in file1 being searched for? 

For example - if file2 had 1000 entries, and we wanted to find all occurrences of `400`, it would show up at least once in file2 - in the first column (`line400`). Would there be a way to exclude that? maybe with regex, to make sure the text being matched comes after the tab/space?

Comment: Yes, by pre-processing the contents of file1 with sed to put a space in front of each word:

`sed 's/^/ /' file1|grep -of - file2|xargs -I {} grep -o "{}" file3`

or, slightly more elegantly:

`grep -o "$(sed 's/^/ /' file1|grep -of - file2)" file3`

This will now match ' 400' but not just '400' (as in 'line400')

Comment: That's a nice idea - but it unfortunately returns nothing in my terminal

Comment: It works perfectly for me with sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 and grep (GNU grep) 2.20. Check for typos, especially that the sed expression is 's/^/ /'. The way stackexchange shows the code (breaking the line at the space) may have misled you.

Comment: I think the problem was that in file2 - the columns are separated by a tab, instead of a space. `sed 's/^/\t/'` seems to return output that is at least _sort of_ correct. thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

You could use `join` 2 times on a row:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -o 1.1 <(join -1 1 -2 2 <(sort file1) <(sort -k2 file2)) <(sort -k2 file3)
```

Prints only:

```
465
```

First look at the inner `join`. It joins `file1` and `file2` by using the field 1 in `file1` and the field 2 in `file2`.

Then all of this is joined again with `file3`. Notice, the files must be sorted on the join fields (`sort -k`).

Answer (score 1):

```
also(){
    sed 'h;                    #save a copy of the line before edits
         s/[]$\./*^[]/\\&/g;   #literally quote any metachars
         s|.*|/&/c\\|p;        #print first half of sed command
         g;                    #get original copy out of hold space
         s/\\/&&/g;' |         #double-up backslashes
    sed  -nf - -- "$@"         #read stdin script -file
}
```

That function takes a pattern file as stdin and one or more search files as arguments. It writes to its output any line from its pattern file which can be matched in its search files. It is careful to reproduce the original exactly each time. And because it is, you can use it recursively.

```
also <file1 file2 | also file3
```

---

```
456
```

Answer (score 0):

grep should suffice your solution

```
 grep -o "`grep -of file1 file2`" file3
```

the inner grep "`grep -f file1 file2`" will grep the pattern present in file1 and file2 and the pattern returned is searched in file3.

Comment: this doesn't work as written because it needs the -o grep option thus: `grep  -o "$(grep -of file1 file2)" file3`

Comment: got it. it will print the whole line.